# Approach for enforcing a statement is present inside if condition through tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a java project and I am looking for testing frameworks which allows me to enforce a constraint -

*A specific method call on one object can only be called only after invoking another method on another object*:

For example

```
if (validator.someMandatoryCheck()) {
    myObject.performOperation();
}
```

I want to ensure that in my codebase, everywhere `myObject.performOperation()` is called, `validator.someMandatoryCheck()` has to be  called first.

Is there a testing framework that would allow me to achieve this ?

Comment: Mockito ? A mock wrapper on your two classes, with a wrapping implementation that sets a `wasExectued` to true for validator.someMandatoryCheck(), and a wrapping implementation for myObject.performOperation that asserts that wasExecuted is true?

Comment: Why would you need a test case for that? you can use some sort of behavioral design pattern to enforce that constraint. I am not sure if people write unit test cases for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

To test your code snippet, you can use Mockito framework.

```
Mockito.when(validator.someMandatoryCheck()).thenReturns(true);
Mockito.verify(myObject).performOperation();
```

But myObject should be a mock object.
 For more reference on verify method: http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify